# Scan array in x86 assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86-64

I am stuck with trying to scan and store an double word array in x86-64.
I have looked all over and can't seem to find anything that I understand.
My program should scan and print all the elements of a dword array.

I have looked at many examples but I can't seem to use them - they give me compilation errors.
Furthermore, I can't seem to use something like - movq %rsi, [array + 8]

Here is my code:

```
.data
.comm   arr, 800                # int arr[100];
.comm   p, 8                    # int pointer;
.comm   c, 8
.comm   c2, 8
.comm   c3, 8
arr     dd 100 DUP(0)
.text
format1:
        .string "Enter integers followed by EOF\n"

format2:
        .string "%ld"

format3:
        .string "a is %ld\n"

.globl main
main:                                   # main()
        movq    $format1, %rdi          #   printf("Enter integers followed by E
        movq    $0, %rax                #
        call    printf                  #
        movq    $arr, %r8
        movq    $0, c
        movq    $0, c2

        whileloop:
        movq    $format2, %rdi          #   scanf("%ld",&a);
        movq    $p, %rsi                #
        movq    %rsi, %r8
        movq    $0, %rax                #
        call    scanf                   #
        cmpq    $0, %rsi                #   if(arr[ptr] == 0)
        je      endwhileloop
        addq    $8, %r8
        addq    $1, c
        jmp     whileloop
        endwhileloop:
        movq    $format3, %rdi #   printf("a=%ld",a);
        movq    $p,%rsi       #
        movq    (%rsi),%rsi    #
        movq    $0, %rax       #
        call    printf         #
        ret
```

This isn't storing the array properly for a fact in 'arr'.
Thanks!

Comment: what assembler are you using? this looks like gas syntax except for the comments and directives.

Comment: also: why not just write a simple program in C, then disassemble it?

Comment: AMD x86-64. I've tried that as well. Will give it a go again. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I'm using gas. GNU.

Comment: better yet, `gcc -S -m64 test.c` will produce assembly output test.s

Comment: I got your assembly to compile and run by removing the `arr dd 100 dup(0)` line (which is nasm syntax and duplicates existing gas directive above) and changing `main` to `_start`. however, it only prints the last number entered and then segfaults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seems to work, perhaps not exactly as desired. you had a few problems including your final printf was being called only once; the `ret` directive at the end causing a segfault because there was nothing to which to return; and the line in nasm syntax `arr dd 100 dup(0)`.

here's the corrected assembly language:

```
.data
.comm   arr, 800                # int arr[100];
.comm   p, 8                    # int pointer;
.comm   c, 8
.comm   c2, 8
.comm   c3, 8
.text
format1:
        .string "Enter integers followed by EOF\n"

format2:
        .string "%ld"

format3:
        .string "a is %ld\n"

.globl _start
_start:                                 # main()
        movq    $format1, %rdi          #   printf("Enter integers followed by E
        movq    $0, %rax                #
        call    printf                  #
        movq    $arr, %r8
        movq    $0, c
        movq    $0, c2

whileloop:
        movq    $format2, %rdi          #   scanf("%ld",&a);
        movq    $p, %rsi                #
        movq    %rsi, %r8
        movq    $0, %rax                #
        call    scanf                   #
        cmpq    $0, %rsi                #   if(arr[ptr] == 0)
        je      endwhileloop
        addq    $8, %r8
        addq    $1, c
        movq    $format3, %rdi #   printf("a=%ld",a);
        movq    $p,%rsi       #
        movq    (%rsi),%rsi    #
        movq    $0, %rax       #
        call    printf         #
        jmp     whileloop
endwhileloop:
        xor     %rbx, %rbx
        call    exit
```

and the Makefile for my 32-bit Debian system:

```
all: test
%.o: %.as
    as -o $@ --64 $<
%: %.o
    ld -melf_x86_64 -o $@ -lc \
     -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 \
     $<
```

output:

```
jcomeau@aspire:~/stackoverflow/19780206$ ./test
Enter integers followed by EOF
1234 5667 67899
a is 1234
a is 5667
a is 67899
^D
```